# Mantain aspect ratio in matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Single plot case:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_acf(series, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Multiplot case:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3)

series.plot(ax=ax[0])
plot_acf(series, ax=ax[1])
plot_pacf(series, ax=ax[2])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

In the multiplot case the individual plots are squeezed on the Y direction (so the aspect ratio of the individual plots is changed, while the aspect ratio of the overall figure is not changed).
How can I maintain the aspect ratio of the individual plots when I make a multiplot?

Comment: You need to explicitly set the desired figure size. E.g. `plt.subplots(3, figsize=(6.4, 4.8*3))`. If the figure is already created earlier, you could do `w, h = fig.get_size_inches()` and then `fig.set_size_inches(w, h*3)`

Comment: Matplotlib assumes you know the figure dimension and want the subplots to fit inside.  The alternative layout method, where you know the subplot dimension and want the figure to grow in size is possible, just not what is done by default.  As @JohanC says above, you can do this manually.  I also think this layout method is one of the marque features of proplot: https://proplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/